# listnav not working with jQuery 1.6.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

.listnav isn't working with jQuery 1.6.2.  Since I've never used listnav before, I figure I'm probably doing something wrong.  I've taken out a lot of the extra code.  Also, I do have a .listnav css and I am referencing jquery-1.6.2.min.js and jquery.listnav-2.1.js.  My code works as far as getting data back, but when I get to the line $("#nasphoneUserList" + _phoneusertabid).listnav(); 
I get "Object doesn't support this property or method"  error

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // header div
    var divNP = $("<div />", {id: "divNasPhoneUser" })
    .addClass('reportheader-container')
    .appendTo(currtab);
    $("<span />", {
        id: "nasPhoneTitle" + _phoneusertabid,
        text: "NAS Phone List"
    }).addClass("reportheader-title label")
      .appendTo(divNP);

   //outer control container
    divPhListCtrls = $("<div />", { id:    "nasphoneUser_divlistCtrls" + phoneusertabid }).appendTo(currtab);
    // phone list  <ul> div container
    divPhList = $("<div />", { id: "nasphoneUserList-nav" })
        .addClass("phonelist-list")
        .appendTo(divPhListCtrls);
    // add <ul> for phone list
    $("<ul />", { id: "nasphoneUserList" })
    .addClass("")
    .appendTo(divPhList);

    //couple of ajax calls, the last of which has the function    below as its callback
});


function nasPhoneUser_buildPhoneList(data) {
    var ulphonelst = $("#nasphoneUserList" + _phoneusertabid);
    $(ulphonelst).find('li').remove();
    var arrMetadata = GetNormalizeMetadataClean(data);
    $.each(arrMetadata, function (i) {
       $("<li />", { href: "#", text: this.DisplayName + " - " +    this.Extension }).appendTo(ulphonelst);
    });
    $("#nasphoneUserList" + _phoneusertabid).listnav();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded the `listnav` library?

Comment: yes, but our pages do have a very different architect.  I'll move the link to the host page and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: listnav hasn't been updated since 2009 - tons of jquery changes since then. Try testing it with an older version of jQuery. After you find the last version it works with, read the changelog for that version, then patch the code.

Comment: tried doing comment above, no help

Comment: listnav will work when I declare the html elements like <div> and <ul> statically.  But when trying to create listnav from elements that were created dynamically in $(document).ready( function, it apparently can't resolve them.  I've changed it to static creation and it working fairly well now.

Answer (score 2):

I have actually modified ListNav and published it on GitHub.
I iterated it to 2.2 and made it compatible all the way up to the latest version of jQuery. This should fix all your problems with ListNav and jQuery 1.6.2

Take a look: https://github.com/esteinborn/jquery-listnav

Comment: does it have a destroy function so that I can rebind a list more than once? If not, how can I make one? help, please.